# Does the Impersonator need access to the whole tenant to be able to connect

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, impersonation

I'm using a plugin that helps me to store and index my mails. To get this running, I first need to register my Mail Service by using the Impersonator account. But when I do this I get an error that something went wrong when trying to establish the connection.

Question: Is it mandatory that the Impersonator has access to the whole tenant or is it also possible that he has only the right for specific folders?

Answer (score 0):

With EWS Impersonation your impersonating the owner of the Mailbox so it will give you access to every folder in the Mailbox and it can't be constrained in anyway. If you use delegation instead eg a specific account with its own mailbox you can then grant that account rights to specific shared folder eg the Inbox of UserA ect using add-MailboxFolderPermissions.